# How do you use a string declared in the project file in sys.argv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have this code in `test.py`:

```
import sys
a = 'alfa'
b = 'beta'
c = 'gamma'
d = 'delta'
print(sys.argv[1])
```

Running `python test.py a` would then return `a`. How can I make it return `alfa` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a dictionary that maps to those strings:

```
mapping = {'a': 'alfa', 'd': 'delta', 'b': 'beta', 'c': 'gamma'}
```

Then when you get your `sys.argv[1]` just access the value from your dictionary as:

```
print(mapping.get(sys.argv[1]))
```

Demo:

File: `so_question.py`

```
import sys

mapping = {'a': 'alfa', 'd': 'delta', 'b': 'beta', 'c': 'gamma'}
user_var = sys.argv[1]

user_var_value = mapping.get(user_var)

print("user_var_value is: {}".format(user_var_value))
```

In a shell:

```
▶ python so_question.py a
user_var_value is: alfa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `globals` or `locals`:

```
import sys


a = 'alfa'
b = 'beta'
c = 'gamma'
d = 'delta'

print(globals().get(sys.argv[1]))
# or 
print(locals().get(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: Though this is correct it should not be used, the mapping approach of the other answer is much better.

Comment: @try-catch-finally, care to elaborate on why?

Comment: Because it teaches beginners to carrying on declaring global variables and referencing them via those methods which is a bad practice. (There are 20 greek letters available and the next question how to programmatically import global variables in functions will come up soon). Aside from that this approach may allow passing any name to access any global variable which might be a security issue if not properly checked.